# Executing Multiple Stored Procedures with single Connection

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-2010, vba

I have a design, described below, that needs to execute (potentially) multiple stored procedures one right after the other.

```
   Dim cn As ADODB.Connection: Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
   Dim srv As String: srv = GetValue("tblBrandDatabase", abbr)
   Dim db As String: db = GetValue("tblBrandDatabase", abbr, 3)
   Dim connstr As String
   connstr = "Provider=SQLNCLI10;Server=" & srv & _
               ";Database=" & db & _
               ";Trusted_Connection=yes"

   cn.Open connstr

   ProcessEmplData wb, cn
   If (cn.State = adStateOpen) Then cn.Close

   cn.Open connstr
   Dim cmd As ADODB.Command: Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
   With cmd
      Set .ActiveConnection = cn

      'Process the new Imported Employee Data
      .CommandText = "Process_EmplData"
      .CommandText = adCmdStoredProc
      .Execute
   End With

   If (cn.State = adStateOpen) Then cn.Close
   Set cn = Nothing
```

#### Question:

How can i get this to be successful without getting the Error Code `Run-time error -2147217900 (80040e14) - Incorrect syntax near '4'`?

Needs to be applicable to 2007/2010 as we still have both version deployed in the field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you see it yet?
4 is the value of `adCmdStoredProc`. You overwrite `.CommandText` with that. Use `.CommandType` instead of the second `.CommandText`.

Comment: I was code blind, evidently.  TYVM, had been lookin at the code for 2-3 hrs and finally gave up and through it here ;)